# batch: if..then..else nested make me mad

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, nested-if

I've wrote a subroutine with some if..else nested
Unfortunately i can't understand why my code are executed before and after the "ELSE" (!!)
I read it for hours, but i don't find any error.. can you help me?
I copied the code (with a lot of echo-debugs) and the output

This is my little code:

```
 setlocal
 set debug=echo 
 %debug%   # %~0: %*
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=;" %%a in ('"%*"') do (set dir=%%~a& set own=%%~b)
 %debug%   - dir="!dir!"
 %debug%   - own="!own!"
 %debug%   -+ analisi cartella: "!dir!"
 if exist "!dir!" (
    %debug%    x la cartella esiste già, passo oltre
    ) else (
    %debug%    - la cartella non esite quindi la creo
    mkdir "!dir!" || echo   [E] non sono riuscito a creare la cartella&& echo %err3_txt% [dir:!dir!] 1>&2 && exit %err3_id%
    )
 %debug%   -+ analisi proprietario: "!own!"
 for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%x in ('"!own!\\"') do (set own1=%%~x& set own2=%%~y)
 if [!own!] equ [!own:~0,1! ] (
    %debug%    x il proprietario non è stato specificato quindi non va cambiato, passo oltre
    ) else (
    %debug%    - own1: "!own1!" 
    %debug%    - own2: "!own2!"
    if [%own2%] equ [] (
   %debug%    - il proprietario ha un dominio implicito, lo calcolo
       set ownn=%own1%
       set ownd=%userdomain%
       ) else (
       %debug%    - il proprietario ha un dominio esplicitamente indicato
       set ownd="input non valido"
       if /i [!own1!] equ [L] set ownd=%computername%
       if /i [!own1!] equ [D] set ownd=%userdomain%
       if "%ownd%" equ "input non valido" (echo    [E] il dominio esplitamente indicato non è riconosciuto: !own1!& echo %err4_txt% [dir:!dir!][own:!own!] 1>&2 & exit %err4_id%)
       )
    %debug%    - la configurazione prevede l'impostazione del seguente proprietario: !ownd!\!ownn!
    )
 %debug%   x done.
```

this is my output :

```
# :CSG_check_fs: C:; ;

 - dir="C:"

 - own=" "

 -+ analisi cartella: "C:"

  x la cartella esiste giÓ, passo oltre

 -+ analisi proprietario: " "

  x il proprietario non Þ stato specificato quindi non va cambiato, passo oltre

  - own1: " "

  - own2: ""

  - il proprietario ha un dominio implicito, lo calcolo

  - la configurazione prevede l'impostazione del seguente proprietario: CSG\    

x done.
```

in particular, let us appropriate commands are executed BEFORE and AFTER the else clause!!!
why??? this thing is incredible!! or am i too tired?

Comment: Try to tone down, Someone could mistake this as a rant.

Comment: imo you should kill all %debug% lines & the code will run :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly very odd. CMD seems to be having a real problem with this very complex statement (and so do I...) :

```
 if [!own!] equ [!own:~0,1! ] (
    %debug%    x il proprietario non è stato specificato quindi non va cambiato, passo oltre
    ) else (
    %debug%    - own1: "!own1!" 
    %debug%    - own2: "!own2!"
    if [%own2%] equ [] (
   %debug%    - il proprietario ha un dominio implicito, lo calcolo
       set ownn=%own1%
       set ownd=%userdomain%
       ) else (
       %debug%    - il proprietario ha un dominio esplicitamente indicato
       set ownd="input non valido"
       if /i [!own1!] equ [L] set ownd=%computername%
       if /i [!own1!] equ [D] set ownd=%userdomain%
       if "%ownd%" equ "input non valido" (echo    [E] il dominio esplitamente indicato non è riconosciuto: !own1!& echo %err4_txt% [dir:!dir!][own:!own!] 1>&2 & exit %err4_id%)
       )
    %debug%    - la configurazione prevede l'impostazione del seguente proprietario: !ownd!\!ownn!
    )
```

Looking at

```
if [!own!] equ [!own:~0,1! ] (
```

You may think that this should be evaluated, with `OWN` set to a single space, as

```
if [ ] equ [ ] (
```

Which should generate a syntax error because the third token in the command is `]` and that's not a valid comparison-operator. The `!var!` confuses matters because it can't be evaluated until EXECUTION TIME - and by then, the parser has finished its work.

The correct form is

```
 if "%own%" equ "%own:~0,1% " (
```

because the parser can then substitute the CURRENT (ie. PARSE-TIME) value of `own` and the syntax is "quoted string" operator "another quoted string"

I'm sure that this change would solve the major part of the problem.

Similarly,

```
    if [%own2%] equ [] (
```

should be

```
    if "%own2%" equ "" (
```

or even (my preference)

```
    if not defined own2
```

- and the same goes for the other `IF [..] equ [...]` constructs.

Finally, in the sequence

```
       set ownd="input non valido"
       if /i [!own1!] equ [L] set ownd=%computername%
       if /i [!own1!] equ [D] set ownd=%userdomain%
       if "%ownd%" equ "input non valido" (echo    [E] il dominio ...
```

there's a small problem (other than the `if..[...`

`ownd` may be SET within the code, but the `%ownd%` in the last of these lines will have the PARSE-TIME value of `ownd` substituted, so it's unlikely to contain the target string. **Here's** where you **NEED** `!var!` because the value of `var` is being changed by the code and you want the `changed` value, not the value as it stood when the statement was `parsed`.

HTH

Comment: YEAAAA! Replacing the [] with the "" it works!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Imo this might be not perfect, but please keep in mind, this is no de-bugging service here & I'm not your father, Luke.

```
@ echo off&setlocal

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=;" %%a in ("%*") do (set dir=%%~a& set own=%%~b)
if not exist "%dir%" mkdir "%dir%" || echo   [E] non sono riuscito a creare la cartella&& echo %err3_txt% [dir:%dir%]&& exit %err3_id%
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%x in ("%own%\\") do (set own1=%%~x& set own2=%%~y)

if not [%own%] equ [%own:~0,1%] (
   if [%own2%] equ [] (
      set ownn=%own1%
      set ownd=%userdomain%
    ) else (
      set "ownd=input non valido"
      if /i [%own1%] equ [L] set ownd=%computername%
      if /i [%own1%] equ [D] set ownd=%userdomain%
      if "%ownd%" equ "input non valido" (echo    [E] il dominio esplitamente indicato non è riconosciuto: %own1%& echo %err4_txt% [dir:%dir%][own:%own%]& exit %err4_id%)
    )
)
```